# Locate and slice off overlap in data array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, slice

I want to get rid of the overlap in my longitude data at the end of the array (0 to 20.4 degrees). So in the end I want the values to be 0-360.

I am going to be doing this for many arrays with a variable number of values that overlap, so I cannot just slice off the last three values. Also, the beginning and end points won't always be 0 & 360 or 20.4. I also want to preserve the order of the values so that I can slice off the corresponding values in the latitude array.

Most of the information on the internet is about getting rid of duplicate values, but none of my values because of the numbers trailing the decimal.

```
lon = np.array([0.9783,20.1276,40.3784,60.0987,80.3748,100.9999,120.4567,140.3543,160.2342,180.3453,200.8874,220.2346,240.5554,260.5676,280.4345,300.4454,320.5654,340.6432,360.3343,0.0124,10.3213,20.4355])
```

I've tried brainstorming ways to do it with <, >, =, np.where, or if/else without success so far.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: `lon[(lon >= 0) & (lon <= 20.4)]`?

Comment: Wouldn't that only give me the values between 0 and 20.4?

Comment: So, you want to get ride of those? Use the negated mask : `lon[~((lon >= 0) & (lon <= 20.4))]`?

Comment: I want to keep the values at the beginning of the array that are between 0-20.4 and get rid of the overlapping values at the end of the array between 0-20.4. So, in the end I want my values to be from 0-360 instead of 0-->360-->20.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of all the elements after the `data` drops down to the start again (so in your case only the `elements` up to the 
`360.3343` before the `0.0124`), the following `for-loop` should do the job.

```
stop = False
for i in range(len(lon)-1):
    if stop and lon[i] > lon[0]:
        lon = lon[:i]
        break
    if lon[i] > lon[i+1]:
        stop = True
```

which with the `data` you gave for `lon` in the question:

```
lon = np.array([0.9783,20.1276,40.3784,60.0987,80.3748,100.9999,120.4567,140.3543,160.2342,180.3453,200.8874,220.2346,240.5554,260.5676,280.4345,300.4454,320.5654,340.6432,360.3343,0.0124,10.3213,20.4355]):
```

modifies `lon` to:

```
array([   0.9783,   20.1276,   40.3784,   60.0987,   80.3748,  100.9999, 120.4567,  140.3543,  160.2342,  180.3453,  200.8874,  220.2346, 240.5554,  260.5676,  280.4345,  300.4454,  320.5654,  340.6432, 360.3343])
```

---

To demonstrated this *updated* solution with:

```
lon = np.array([50 ,110, 200, 340, 1, 10, 25, 80, 90, 130])
```

we get:

```
array([ 50, 110, 200, 340,   1,  10,  25])
```

Hopefully this finally does what you want!

Comment: This works when my start value is 0 and my end value is 360, but when I tried it with another start/end point (50) L would only return values between 50 and 360. New array used `lon2 = lon = np.array([50,110,200,340,1,10,25,80,90,130])`

Comment: @Rose You didn't specify that well enough in the question, the `3` answers posted all work in the way my answer does, you need to be more *specific*... Nevertheless, I will see what I can do

Comment: Direct quote from my question "Also, the beginning and end points won't always be 0 & 360 or 20.4"

Comment: @Rose Sorry, I hadn't seen that as you edited the post when I was writing mine! I should have checked...

Comment: It's fine. I appreciate you taking the time to write an answer.

Comment: @Rose I have updated the answer now to fit your requirement!

Answer (score 1):

@Joe Iddon's answer will work, but if you want to avoid loops, you can do something like this:

```
diff = np.diff(lon)
drops = np.flatnonzero(diff < 0)
if len(drops) > 0:
    # Only do this if there is a wrap around
    end_index = drops[0] + 1
    lon = lon[:end_index]
```

And you can then use `end_index` to slice other matching arrays too (e.g. latitude).

Note that this doesn't do any fixing for values outside of [0..360] - you'll have to do that separately, depending on how you want to deal with them.

---

**Update for new requirement:**

```
assert len(lon) > 0
above_first = (lon >= lon[0]).astype(int)
diffs = np.diff(above_first)
overlap_indices = np.flatnonzero(diffs > 0)
if len(overlap_indices) > 0:
    end_index = overlap_indices[0] + 1
    lon = lon[:end_index]
```

This will work even if the overlap wraps around multiple times.

Comment: @Ixop This works when my start value is 0 and my end value is 360, but when I tried it with another start/end point (50) L would only return values between 50 and 360. New array  used `lon2 = lon = np.array([50,110,200,340,1,10,25,80,90,130])`

Comment: That wasn't made clear in the question. Just saying that the start value may not be 0 doesn't imply that you want to keep values that have rolled around after 0. An additional example would have made all the difference. I will update my answer to satisfy the new requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Ixop 's idea:

```
dL = np.diff(lon)
ix = np.argmax(dL<0)+1
L = lon[0:ix]
```

You can write the same in 1 line:

```
L = lon[0:np.argmax(np.diff(lon)<0)+1]
```

Comment: This works when my start value is 0 and my end value is 360, but when I tried it with another start/end point (50) L would only return values between 50 and 360. New array I used `lon2 = lon = np.array([50,110,200,340,1,10,25,80,90,130])`

Comment: Additional requirement, obviously. So, based on lon2, what is the desired output ? `[50,110,200,340,1,10,25]` ?

Comment: Yes, and it was a requirement listed in the question.

Answer (score 1):

**New solution**: start from the end of lon2 and compare with the first element of lon2

```
lon2 = np.array([50,110,200,340,1,10,25,80,90,130])
#lon2 = lon

ix = np.argmax(lon2[::-1] < lon2[0])
L2 = lon2[0:-ix]
```

gives

```
with lon2 =  [ 50 110 200 340   1  10  25]
```

and

```
with lon =  [  9.78300000e-01   2.01276000e+01   4.03784000e+01   6.00987000e+01
   8.03748000e+01   1.00999900e+02   1.20456700e+02   1.40354300e+02
   1.60234200e+02   1.80345300e+02   2.00887400e+02   2.20234600e+02
   2.40555400e+02   2.60567600e+02   2.80434500e+02   3.00445400e+02
   3.20565400e+02   3.40643200e+02   3.60334300e+02   1.24000000e-02]
```

Comment: If this answer works for you, then you are kindly invited to click the green "accepted" button left of the answer area. Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
tmp = lon - lon[0]
tmp[tmp<0] += 360
sliced = lon[:np.where(np.diff(tmp) < 0)[0][0]+1]
```